# How to display user profile image in circle?

Tags: css, image

I am developing a site where the users' profile image needs to display in a circle. There are many circles on this site and the circle size can vary.

I can display square images properly but with vertical and horizontal images I face a problem.

I have to display the image in a circle with the below criteria:

- Suppose image size is `500x300`. The image should crop 100px off of the right and left sides, so that the center of the image is shown. Now the image should be `300x300`, centered. Then I need to make a circle from that image. OR hide 100px of the right and left of the image using CSS.
- If image size is `300x500`, then the top and bottom area should be hidden using CSS

What do I have to do to fix this? CSS-only answers are best for me, if possible.

Comment: You could use `border-radius`

Answer (score 84, accepted):

#### `background-size`

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) -
[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/) - [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)

As the image sizes are variable, you want to make sure they `cover` the div as well as being `center`ed within it.

Adding the `border-radius: 50%;` will give you the circle effect.

```css
.user {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.one {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/400x200');
}

.two {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/200x200');
}

.three {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/200x400');
}
```

```html
<div class="user one">
</div>

<div class="user two">
</div>

<div class="user three">
</div>
```

In practice, you wouldn't want to have a class for each image, so you'd specify it with an inline style in the markup:

```
<div class="user" style="background-image:url('path/to/user/img.png')"></div>
```

---

#### `object-fit`

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) - [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/) - [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)

A newer alternative is to use the `object-fit` property on a regular `<img>` tag. This does not work in IE or older versions of Edge.

```css
.user {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;

  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200" class="user">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="user">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x400" class="user">
```

Answer (score 8):

set the image as background, centered.

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

css:

```
.image{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%; /*don't forget prefixes*/
  background-image: url("path/to/image");
  background-position: center center;
  /* as mentioned by Vad: */
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javasluud/4buzasuj/)

Comment: Prefixes are not a concern anymore unless you want to support such browsers like Safari 4

Comment: @HashemQolami: true, but better safe than sorry ;)

Comment: Also add `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bootstrap you have class img-circle to do this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This answer lacks detail and so isn't very useful. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>  
<head>
<style>
#circle
{
border-radius:50% 50% 50% 50%;  
width:300px;
height:300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="skin-tone.jpg"
id="circle">
</body>
</html>
```