# make picture fit in css circle

Tags: html, css

Is there a way where you can make a picture fit automatically in a css circle? Fx if a user add a picture there is 500px * 500px, but the circle is 100px * 100px. When I upload a picture now, the picture is just filling out the screen, instead of staying inside the circle.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>


  #circle
 {
   border-radius:50% 50% 50% 50%;  
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
 </style>

</head>
<body>
   <img src="skin-tone.jpg" id="circle">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code seems to be working fine. Take a look here - https://jsbin.com/zanubuloki/edit?html,css,output. Or may be I don't understand the question completely.

Comment: What is the browser and version where you're trying this code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685227/how-to-display-user-profile-image-in-circle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this CSS

```
#circle {
    background: skin-tone.jpg;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius:50% 50% 50% 50%;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: @Julie24 I'm just curious, but what browser are you using? Because your previous code works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Hello JordyV. I use chrome. After I add background-size and background skin tone it is working. I was thinking if I have to center the circle, how should I do that? with margin or?

Comment: You can try to center it by setting the following CSS in the parent element: `text-align: center;`

Comment: @Julie24 Found your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685227/how-to-display-user-profile-image-in-circle

Comment: Thank you. This also works: display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing it but one simple way is given below:

```
 #circle{
     background: url("imageUrl.jpg");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     background-position: center;
     border-radius: 50%;
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What you have to do is to set a max-width and max-height to the img element. For example, you can say to your img to be of `max-width:100px` and `max-height:100px`.

Comment: I can see that the answer is getting minus here. I used height: 100px; width: 100px; What is the difference between that, and then the max-height and max-width?

Comment: As your image has a fixed size of `100px` its size will never change, unless you do this with javascript (or change your code)... so you don't need to create `max` or `min` limits.

Comment: Sometimes I had troubles with that on Safari Browser.